# Sum Formula Proofs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So, I'm trying to prove the following sum formula, and I can't really get it to work out correctly :

[image]

where ab = $2\pi$ and G = Fourier Transform of g. How would I approach a proof of this formula?  Usually, I see this type of formula presented very differently in a lot of different resources,, and it's throwing me off.

Here is what my textbook is doing.  I don't really understand the substitution for the cosine partial sum or the N->infinity part.  Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Why the tag "pde"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One Normalization of the Fourier Transform**

There are a several ways to normalize the Fourier Transform. The way I find nicest is to define
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-2\pi  ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Define
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(x+k)\tag{2}
$$
Then $g$ has period $1$. Plugging $x=0$ into $(2)$ gives
$$
g(0)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(k)\tag{3}
$$
For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the coefficients of the Fourier Series are
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{g}(n)
&=\int_0^1g(x)\,e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\int_0^1f(x+k)\,e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\hat{f}(n)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Inverting the Fourier Series, we get
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n)e^{2\pi inx}\tag{5}
$$
Plugging $x=0$ into $(5)$ and applying $(4)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
g(0)
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n)\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(n)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$(3)$ and $(6)$ give the [Poisson Summation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula):
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(n)\tag{7}
$$

---

Let $f(x)=g(ax)$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(n)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(ax) e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1a\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) e^{-2\pi inx/a}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1a\hat{g}(n/a)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(8)$ gives the scaled version of $(7)$:
$$
\sqrt{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(an)=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n/a)\tag{9}
$$
Equation $(9)$ is the equivalent of the equation in the question for the Fourier Transform defined in $(1)$. To get the equation in the question, we need to use a different normalization of the Fourier Transform.

---

**Another Normalization of the Fourier Transform**

If we define the Fourier Transform as
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}
$$
and define
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(x+2\pi k)\tag{2a}
$$
then $g$ has period $2\pi$ and plugging $x=0$ into $\mathrm{(2a)}$ gives
$$
g(0)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(2\pi k)\tag{3a}
$$
For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the coefficients of the Fourier Series are
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{g}(n)
&=\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)\,e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}f(x+2\pi k)\,e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\hat{f}(n)\tag{4a}
\end{align}
$$
Inverting the Fourier Series, we get
$$
g(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n)e^{inx}\tag{5a}
$$
Plugging $x=0$ into $\mathrm{(5a)}$ and applying $\mathrm{(4a)}$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
g(0)
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n)\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(n)\tag{6a}
\end{align}
$$
$\mathrm{(3a)}$ and $\mathrm{(6a)}$ give the [Poisson Summation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula):
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(2\pi n)=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(n)\tag{7a}
$$

---

Let $f(x)=g(ax)$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(n)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(ax) e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1a\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) e^{-inx/a}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1a\hat{g}(n/a)\tag{8a}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $\mathrm{(8a)}$ gives the scaled version of $\mathrm{(7a)}$:
$$
\sqrt{2\pi a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(2\pi an)=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{g}(n/a)\tag{9a}
$$
$\mathrm{(9a)}$ is the equation in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Express the sum as a geometric series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \cos{n z} = \operatorname{Re}{\left [\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i n z} \right ]} $$

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i n z} &= e^{i z}\frac{e^{i N z}-1}{e^{i z}-1} \\ &= e^{i z/2} e^{i N z/2} \frac{e^{i N z/2}-e^{-i N z/2}}{e^{i z/2}-e^{-i z/2}}\\ &= e^{i (N+1) z/2} \frac{\sin{(N z/2)}}{\sin{(z/2)}}\end{align} $$

Taking real parts, we have

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N \cos{n z} &= \frac{\sin{(N z/2)} \cos{((N+1) z/2)}}{\sin{(z/2)}}\end{align} $$

Use the fact that

$$2 \sin{a} \cos{b} = \sin{(a+b)}+\sin{(a-b)}$$

to see that

$$\sin{(N z/2)} \cos{((N+1) z/2)} = \frac12 \left [\sin{((2 N+1) z/2)} - \sin{(z/2)} \right ]$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N \cos{n z} &= \frac{\sin{((2 N+1) z/2)}}{2 \sin{(z/2)}} - \frac12\end{align}$$

Let $z=\lambda a$ and the result follows.

Comment: Wow, that's actually a very nifty way to rewrite the cosine sum and much clearer after seeing it (thank you!).  Though, it would have been nice for my textbook to flesh out those details a bit more.  Any idea what's going on with the N -> $\infty$ portion?  I looked into Fourier's single-integral theorem, and I can't spot any similarities.

Comment: @Incognito: I have been studying Fourier analysis for decades; I have never heard of the single-integral theorem.  Google doesn't help.  Please state it for the benefit of your readers.